# Is there workaround to install hyper-v in VM guest with Linux host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

I wonder if there are any workaround to install hyper-v on VM hosted on Linux base machine. My daily system is Kubuntu 20.10. I have lot of ram on my computer and would like to setup a windows lab using Virtualbox. After quick search on google, it seems that  installing hyper-v only possible when host and guest are windows (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization). This borders me a lot because I cannot install windows as host and I don't have any other computer to install on it.

Any idea ?

Comment: You basically give the answer. Not possible unless you have a Windows Host. Also, you can only nest hyper-v to hyper-v. So even if you were to have linux with virtualbox, install windows inside and try to install hyper-v in there, it would not work because VT-x is not passed through. Although you may still be able to use hyper-v in a 32-bit environment without VT-x though... You could test that. Couldn't you dualboot windows next to linux? One way (not optimal) is to have windows at the top with Hyper-V and run linux in a VM. Dual boot is the way to go.

Comment: There are numerous Hypervisors for Linux Hyper-V isn’t necessary to have virtual machines on a Linux host

Comment: Instead of VirtualBox, use KVM, you can run a Hyper-V host in a KVM VM.

Comment: I have been running nested Hyper-V as well as ESXi under Workstation.
https://www.vmwareblog.org/build-home-lab-using-pc-part-2-vmware-workstation/
You can try using Workstation. As mentioned, alternatively use KVM, it is much more flexible and can run everything nested.